# SelectInput (inside Table Cell) does not read input$ID value after any change in the inputs it is based on

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I have SelectInputs inside cells in a table. I am able to read the value from the selectInput as long as the actionButton is clicked once. But after clicking the actionButton again, it does not read the value from the SelectInput from the table Cell.

Here is a reproducible example for my code:

```
master_table <- data.frame("class_col" = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
                           "all_student"=c("CA1", "CA2", "CA3", "CA4", "CA5", "CB1", "CB2", "CB3", "CB4", "CB5", "CC1", "CC2", "CC3", "CC4", "CC5"))

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  selectInput("class_input", label = "Class", choices= sort(c("Select Class"='', unique(master_table$class_col))), selected=NULL),
  shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id="alert", tags$h5("* Please Select Class ", style = "color:red"))),
  actionBttn(inputId = 'go', label='Go!'),
  shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id='hidden_table', DT::dataTableOutput('student_select_table'))),
  textOutput("text_output_for_selected_Student_at_Row1"))
 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mod = reactiveValues(student_reactive=0)
  
  observeEvent(input$class_input, {
    student_table = data.table('student_input_col' = 1:5)
    
    mod$student_reactive <- reactive({
      for (i in 1:nrow(student_table)){
        student_table$student_input_col[i] <- as.character(selectInput(inputId = paste0("student_row", i),
                                                                       label=NULL,
                                                                       choices = sort(c("Select Student"='', master_table$all_student[master_table$class_col == input$class_input]))))
      }
      return(student_table)
      })
    })


observeEvent(input$go, {

if(nchar(input$class_input)<1){
  shinyjs::showElement("alert")
  shinyjs::hideElement("hidden_table")
} else {
shinyjs::hideElement("alert")
shinyjs::showElement("hidden_table")

output$student_select_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  datatable(mod$student_reactive(),
            class= "cell-border",
            rownames = FALSE, width = "80%",escape = FALSE,
            selection = "single",
            options = list(dom='t', paging=FALSE, ordering=FALSE, info=FALSE,
                           rowCallback = JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '40px')}"),
                           preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                           drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))
            )
  })
}
})

output$text_output_for_selected_Student_at_Row1 <- renderText(paste0("Text for Student at Row1 = ", input$student_row1))

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server))
```

This works fine when I run it one time. It also updates the Students in the table cell drop-down when I change class_input.
But the value in the `text_output_for_selected_Student_at_Row1` does not update if I change the value of class_input or if I click on the actionButton again.

Comment: You are updating choices in your `selectInput` with the same `inputId`.  That is not allowed.  You should update with `updateSelectInput()` or use new `ID`s.

Comment: That did not help. I tried with updating choices as c("a", "b", "c", "d" "e") instead of using the inputId. But my previous issue is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, one way to resolve your issue is to create a new `ID` each time a user selects a new `class_col`.  We can attach the `class` and a `counter` to define the new `inputId`.  Please note that the table is updated only after you click the `actionButton`.  Try this

```
master_table <- data.frame("class_col" = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
                           "all_student"=c("CA1", "CA2", "CA3", "CA4", "CA5", "CB1", "CB2", "CB3", "CB4", "CB5", "CC1", "CC2", "CC3", "CC4", "CC5"))

library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  selectInput("class_input", label = "Class", choices= sort(c("Select Class"='', unique(master_table$class_col))), selected=NULL),
  shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id="alert", tags$h5("* Please Select Class ", style = "color:red"))),
  actionBttn(inputId = 'go', label='Go!'),
  shinyjs::hidden(tags$div(id='hidden_table', DT::dataTableOutput('student_select_table'))),
  textOutput("text_output_for_selected_Student_at_Row1"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mod = reactiveValues(student_reactive=0, df=NULL)
  cntr <- reactiveValues(value=0)
  
  k <- eventReactive(input$class_input, {
    cntr$value <- cntr$value+1
    return(cntr$value) })
  observe({print(k())})
  
  observeEvent(input$class_input, {
    student_table = data.table('student_input_col' = 1:5)
    #req(k())
    for (i in 1:nrow(student_table)){
      student_table$student_input_col[i] <- as.character(selectInput(inputId = paste0("student_row", i, input$class_input,k()),
                                                                     label=NULL,
                                                                     choices = sort(c("Select Student"='', master_table$all_student[master_table$class_col == input$class_input]))))
    
    }
    mod$student_reactive <- student_table
      
  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    
    if(nchar(input$class_input)<1){
      shinyjs::showElement("alert")
      shinyjs::hideElement("hidden_table")
    } else {
      shinyjs::hideElement("alert")
      shinyjs::showElement("hidden_table")
      
      mod$df <- mod$student_reactive
    }
  })
  
  output$student_select_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mod$df,
              class= "cell-border",
              rownames = FALSE, width = "80%",escape = FALSE,
              selection = "single",
              options = list(dom='t', paging=FALSE, ordering=FALSE, info=FALSE,
                             rowCallback = JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '40px')}"),
                             preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                             drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))
    )
  })
  
  output$text_output_for_selected_Student_at_Row1 <- renderText(paste0("Text for Student at Row1 = ", input[[paste0("student_row1",input$class_input,k())]]))
  
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server))
```